# Getting a max value of a column with a where filter in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get :

> select MAX(foo) as value from bar where baz=somevalue

equivalent from sqlalchemy,currently tried:

counter = db_session.query(func.max(ProductDefect.defectorderno)).scalar()

This gives me a value,but i coulndt find a way to use where condition

```
counter = ProductDefect.query(func.max(ProductDefect.defectorderno).filter_by(productid=activeproduct.productid)
```

This gives me a syntax error.What is the correct usage?

Comment: Missing/Wrongly placed *parenthesis*? Try: `counter = ProductDefect.query(func.max(ProductDefect.defectorderno).label("value")).filter(ProductDefect.productid == activeproduct.productid)`

Comment: this one gives me a syntax error as well.

Comment: Please post the generated `SQL` statement, which you can see if you enable `echo=True` in `create_engine(...)`

Comment: Modifying the query to 
counter = ProductDefect.query(func.max(ProductDefect.defectorderno)).filter_by(productid=activeproduct.productid) 
should work